# Visual Studio 2012 (C++) - Use included .png file

Tags: c++, resources, textures, sprite

I am encountering yet another problem with DirectX 9 & C++. I have currently been working on 2D games using LPD3DXSPRITE and LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9. I can easily load in textures, however when it comes to distributing a finished game, I need to also distribute all the resources with it (which can be edited, deleted or something, which is not convenient). I know it is possible to import a "resource file" into Visual Studio, however when I refer to it using D3DXCreateTextureFromFile() it does not load it. I have no idea how I would do this.

If this is possible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's a good idea to store game assets in windows resource file.
But if you really want to try it:

**Method 1.**

- [`D3DXCreateTextureFromResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`D3DXCreateTextureFromResourceEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions looks exactly what are you want.

Use case:

```
// suppose we have resource `IDB_SPRITE1` in resource file linked in current executable
// and properly initialized g_pD3dDevice
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 sprite1_texture = 0;
HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromResource( g_pD3dDevice, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                              MAKEINTRESOURCE( SPRITE1 ), &sprite1_texture );
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    // there was error. Check `hr` for error description
}

// no errors: now you can use `sprite1_texture`
```

**Method 2.**

- use [`LoadImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Pass resource via [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro. Get `HBITMAP` returned.
- use [`GetBitmapBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to retrieve pixel data
- use [`D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I've looked this up in the meantime, and I have no idea where to put all these functions. And, I have no idea what the parameters should be in all of these methods. I need a much more thorough explanation of this.

Comment: I've edited answer. Added use case for `D3DXCreateTextureFromResource()`. No sure if I can explain more thorough than source code =)

Comment: Method 1 worked fine, assuming I #include "resource.h". Thanks :)